# unbiased estimation of the variance of $p$ (proportion) of a random sample without replacement

Tags: variance, estimation, proportion, estimators, unbiased-estimator

Given a random sample without replacement of size $n$ from population of size $N$ and $p$ is the estimator of the proportion $P$. How could one show that:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{N-n}{N(N-1)}pq
\end{equation*}

is an unbiased estimation of the variance of $p$?

What I have done, so far:
\begin{equation*}
P = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1} Y_i = \mu
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
S^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum^N_{i=1} (Y_i - P)^2= \frac{1}{N-1}\sum^N_{i=1}( (Y_i)^2 -2Y_iP +(P)^2) =  \frac{1}{N-1} \bigg [ \bigg (\sum^N_{i=1} Y_i^2 \bigg) - NP^2 \bigg ]
\end{equation*}

since,

\begin{equation*}
var[\hat{P}] = (1-f)\frac{S^2}{n} = \bigg ( \frac{N - n}{N} \bigg ) \frac{S^2}{n}
\end{equation*}

then,

\begin{equation*}
var[\hat{P}] = \bigg ( \frac{N - n}{N} \bigg ) \bigg ( \frac{n}{N-1} \bigg ) \bigg [ \bigg (\sum^N_{i=1} Y_i^2 \bigg) - NP^2 \bigg ]
\end{equation*}

But I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Are you sure that is an unbiased estimator of the variance?  It looks to me like a natural estimator and  so possibly biased

Comment: I'm sure it is unbiased